# Laravel most repeated product in each invoice

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have two tables `export_invoices` and `sold_products`.
 Relationship here is one to many (Each invoice have many sold products).

## What I am trying to do:

I am trying to get the most repeated (occurrences) products in export invoices.

`export_invoices` table:

```
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 1     |
| 2  | 1     |
+----+-------+
```

`sold_products` table:

```
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
| id | export_invoice_id | product_id | sold_price |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1                 | 205        | 12         |
| 2  | 1                 | 205        | 15         |
| 3  | 2                 | 205        | 12         |
| 4  | 2                 | 301        | 20         |
| 5  | 2                 | 302        | 30         |
+----+-------------------+------------+------------+
```

Now the most occurrence product report should look like:

```
[
 {
   "product_id": "205",
   "occurrences": "2"
 },
 {
   "product_id": "301",
   "occurrences": "1"
 }
]
```

## What I have tried:

```
$columns = ['sold_products.deleted_at', 'export_invoices.deleted_at'];

        $report_data = ExportInvoice::join('sold_products', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id', '=', 'export_invoices.id')
            ->join('products', 'sold_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->select(
                'sold_products.product_id',
                DB::raw('
                    COUNT(DISTINCT(sold_products.export_invoice_id))
                    as occurrences
                ')
            )
            ->whereYear('export_invoices.date', $year)
            ->where(function($q) use ($columns) {
                foreach ($columns as $column) {
                    $q->whereNull($column);
                }
            })
            ->groupBy('sold_products.product_id', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id')
            ->orderBy('occurrences', 'DESC')
            ->limit(20)
            ->get();
        return $report_data;
```

This return:

```
[
 {
   "product_id": "205",
   "occurrences": "3" // WRONG NUMBER
 },
 {
   "product_id": "301",
   "occurrences": "1"
 }
]
```

Grouping the products is not working

Comment: the title field in export_invoices is useless right?

Comment: int the table you have given there is 3 times the 205 product, so occurrences i believe is the number invoices that has that product as one of the products sold, right? also i can see that this query does not depend to any value, so why can't you write a raw SQL query?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia yes the title field is useless

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia the occurrence is the number of repeated of a product in invoices.. With put in consideration that IF product is repeated more than one time in a single invoice this mean that it is required once only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the group by in order to group the product id and nothing more.
From

```
groupBy('sold_products.product_id', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id')
```

To

```
groupBy('sold_products.product_id')
```

Comment: This return occurrences always equal to 1!
I want the most requested product in invoices

Comment: I used your answer and changed FROM `groupBy('sold_products.product_id', 'sold_products.export_invoice_id')` to `groupBy('sold_products.product_id')` and it worked fine with the expected result.. Can  you please update your answer so I can accept it. It may help someone.